# What did the ancient philosophers think of crystals?

Tags: ancient-philosophy

Does anyone have any quotes by ancient philosophers on what they thought crystals were made of?

Comment: This is a question more suitable for history of science, natural philosophy was its direct precursor.

Comment: Plato (Timaeus 58d-59b) explained that there are two kinds of water: one is liquid, the other is "fusible". The Ancient Greeks referred to quartz as κρύσταλλος (krustallos) derived from the "kruos" meaning "icy cold", because some philosophers (including Theophrastus) apparently believed the mineral to be a form of supercooled ice.  The problem here is that "crystal" for us means something about the atom's arrangement, not just the solid phase (glass, stone, polycrystal....)